# Visual Studio not detected while installing CUDA 7.5 on Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cuda

For the past few days I have installed many versions of visual studio, but nothing is picked up by CUDA 7.5:

[image]

I am on windows 7, what could be the issue?

EDIT: I have versions of Visual Studio that CUDA 7.5 asks for, please refer to the image for what versions I have installed.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I can try that, but I have visual studio versions that are listed as supported, so maybe there is another reason it isn't working? Maybe I need to add some path to environment variables or something like that?

Comment: @RobertCrovella I also have VS 2013 installed, any reason I might have more luck with VS 2013 community edition? I've already gone through many versions so sorry about the pessimism

Comment: I only see C++ redist, but no real VS installation

Answer (score 1):

In your installed programs, more precisely in the screenshot you provide, it seems you have the redist packages but not Visual Studio itself.
Did you really installed Visual Studio ?
Do you know the big difference between the redist packages and the integrated development environment itself ?

Plus, it seems by now Visual Studio 2015 is not yet supported.
See [this page](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#axzz45VuDbpaq) on the documentation from Nvidia.